# Percent sign in form input

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

Need help to make "%" sign show up automatically to my input field when user type number

```
<input type="text" name="ownership" id="ownership" placeholder="2.00%">
```

like here: 
[image]
 If user enter some number it will always add "%" sign in view. Probably should use some js, but I'm not familiar yet.

I have tried This way, but it works for every input

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
   $('input').change(function() {
        $(this).val(function(index, old) { return old.replace() + '%'; });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? This is not a code-writing service.

Comment: does it have to be inside the input box? does it have to be at the end? does it have to only appear after the user starts typing?

Comment: sorry, won't click a *.ru link with a code attached...

Comment: sorry, I forgot to add code:( First post updated

Comment: @jeff sorry man, I thought joxi is enough popular screenshot service to post it here as support thing.  I uploaded image right here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use Boostrap this should work :

```
<div class="input-group mb-3">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="">
  <div class="input-group-append">
    <span class="input-group-text">%</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/uv9s6q02/

Comment: thanks for tip, unfortunately I use UIkit and know about this way with bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing the code would help, but you can test to see if the user has typed a number using regex.

```
input.addEventListener('keyup', () => {
  if (inputvalue.search(/\d/) > -1) { /* add % */ }
});
```